# Extending expression tree

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda, expression

I am new to expression trees and have no idea how to implement the following. Will be thankful for any ideas or links.

I have 2 entities that need mapping to the corresponding view models. I would like mappers to be stand alone expressions that will be reused in variuos parts of my application.

This mapper expression is to convert MainEntity to MainEntityViewModel:

```
public static Expression<Func<MainEntity, MainEntityViewModel>> MainMapper =
    me => new MainEntityViewModel()
        {
            Property1 = me.Property1, // direct mapping
            OtherEntityModel = new OtherEntityViewModel() // here i'd like to use outer expression
                {
                    Name = me.OtherEntityObject.Name,
                    Description = me.OtherEntityObject.Description
                }
        };
```

I would also like my OtherEntity was a separate expression like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<OtherEntity, OtherEntityViewModel>> OtherMapper =
    oe => new OtherEntityViewModel()
        {
            Name = oe.Name,
            Description = oe.Description
        };
```

but i dont have idea how to apply it inside the first mapper. I guess i need to extend first tree somehow (add expression node or whatever) but dont know exactly what to do.
Thank you!
PS: i know about AutoMapper etc, but would like to use manual mappings.

Comment: You will be rebuilding AutoMapper. But it's open source, so why not take a look? Maybe you can borrow some ideas (and give due credit). Further, I don't think anybody is going to write the expression trees for you. At least show some starting point.

Comment: Hi Gert, thanks for reply. Im not asking for whole solution, just would like to know some general principles, keywords or links that will lead me to the answer. I am not familiar with expression trees at the moment. Am i right i need to deal with underlying expression trees and just to add a new node?

Comment: unfortunately i was unable to make AutoMapper work for complex objects that need heavy mappings (nested lists, convertings/castings, flattenings) and must be turned into IQueriable asa result. It gives various unhandled errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static Func<MainEntity, OtherEntity, Func<OtherEntity, OtherEntityViewModel>, MainEntityViewModel> 
                MainMapper = me, oe, oMapper  => new MainEntityViewModel()
                                                    {
                                                        Property1 = me.Property1, // direct mapping
                                                        OtherEntityModel = oMapper.Invoke(oe)
                                                    };


public static Func<OtherEntity, OtherEntityViewModel> 
                OtherMapper = oe => new OtherEntityViewModel()
                                        {
                                            Name = oe.Name,
                                            Description = oe.Description
                                        };
```

I am not quite sure why you need to use Expression, but you can put it back if you want